# LinkedIn post creator

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am try to create an app that will share post on LinkedIn on php. I successfully created access buttons that login to the LinkedIn and show user details. But my next step is to created post functions. For such purpose I create text area with button and add configuration scope "w_share".
But now i did not have any idea about call this function to the button and how to connect textarea with button.
Here is my code..

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['oauth_status']) && $_SESSION['oauth_status'] == 'verified' && !empty($_SESSION['userData'])){
    //Prepare output to show to the user
    $userInfo = $_SESSION['userData'];
    $output = '<div class="login-form" align="left">
        <div class="head">
            <div><img src="'.$userInfo['picture'].'" alt="" style="border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius: 150px; -moz-border-radius: 150px; box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);"/>
            </div>
            
            <style>
body {margin:0;}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
            
            
            <div style="background-color:#996666; height:50px; margin:-60px 0px 0px 20px; padding:5px 0px 0px 100px;" class="topnav">
            
            <a href="'.$userInfo['link'].'" target="_blank">View Profile</a>
            <a href="post.php">Schedule Post</a>
            
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <div class="clear"> </div></div>
        </div>
        
        <form>
        <div>
        <p>'.$userInfo['first_name'].' '.$userInfo['last_name'].'</p>
        <p>'.$userInfo['email'].'</p>
        <p>'.$userInfo['locale'].'</p>
        </div>
        <div id="">
    <textarea id="post_textarea">
    </textarea>
</div>
<div class="div_post_submit">
    <input type="submit" name="Create New Post" value="Create New Post" class="SubmitButton" />
</div>
        </form>
    </div>';
}elseif((isset($_GET["oauth_init"]) && $_GET["oauth_init"] == 1) || (isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']))){
    $client = new oauth_client_class;
    
    $client->client_id = $apiKey;
    $client->client_secret = $apiSecret;
    $client->redirect_uri = $redirectURL;
    $client->scope = $scope;
    $client->debug = false;
    $client->debug_http = true;
    $application_line = __LINE__;
    
    if(strlen($client->client_id) == 0 || strlen($client->client_secret) == 0){
        die('Please go to LinkedIn Apps page https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp= , '.
            'create an application, and in the line '.$application_line.
            ' set the client_id to Consumer key and client_secret with Consumer secret. '.
            'The Callback URL must be '.$client->redirect_uri.'. Make sure you enable the '.
            'necessary permissions to execute the API calls your application needs.');
    }
    
    //If authentication returns success
    if($success = $client->Initialize()){
        if(($success = $client->Process())){
            if(strlen($client->authorization_error)){
                $client->error = $client->authorization_error;
                $success = false;
            }elseif(strlen($client->access_token)){
                $success = $client->CallAPI('http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,location,picture-url,public-profile-url,formatted-name)', 
                'GET',
                array('format'=>'json'),
                array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $userInfo);
            }
        }
        $success = $client->Finalize($success);
    }
    
    if($client->exit) exit;
    
    if($success){
        //Initialize User class
        $user = new User();
        
        //Insert or update user data to the database
        $fname = $userInfo->firstName;
        $lname = $userInfo->lastName;
        $inUserData = array(
            'oauth_provider'=> 'linkedin',
            'oauth_uid'     => $userInfo->id,
            'first_name'    => $fname,
            'last_name'     => $lname,
            'email'         => $userInfo->emailAddress,
            'gender'        => '',
            'locale'        => $userInfo->location->name,
            'picture'       => $userInfo->pictureUrl,
            'link'          => $userInfo->publicProfileUrl,
            'username'      => ''
        );
        
        $userData = $user->checkUser($inUserData);
        
        //Storing user data into session
        $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
        $_SESSION['oauth_status'] = 'verified';
        
        //Redirect the user back to the same page
        header('Location: ./');
    }else{
         $output = '<h3 style="color:red">Error connecting to LinkedIn! try again later!</h3>';
    }
}elseif(isset($_GET["oauth_problem"]) && $_GET["oauth_problem"] <> ""){
    $output = '<h3 style="color:red">'.$_GET["oauth_problem"].'</h3>';
}else{
    $authUrl = '?oauth_init=1';
}
?>
```

I am newbie and searching alot for the idea but did not find any solution.
Kindly please guide what actually steps I have to perform.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code what you have already tried. For better understanding

Comment: Thank Nauman for your reply, I update my question with the part of code html i am doing.

Comment: @NaumanZafar you can also check my index.php whole code here https://codeshare.io/2polAE

if you need further more information let me know i'll share...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: For posting from authenticated user's account (which you have successfully  logged in) You need to utilize LinkedIn API.

You need to call the API's method on `form` submission. After form submission you can receive whatever value you enter in `textarea` and do whatever you want.

Read on here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I check this link earlier. if you checked my whole code then you can see that i already used `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:`  My problem is i did not know where to put it on exact location. Can you read my whole https://codeshare.io/2polAE and guide me about changing.

Comment: @NaumanZafar kindly let me know did you check my code. What mistake I had? Please try to solve this issue. Thanks